# Can we package custom Big Objects into a 2nd generation managed package?

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, big-object

When I try to create a package version via `sfdx force:package:version:create`, it gives an error:

```shell
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  Unexpected file found in package directory: /my-base-path/force-app/main/default/objects/Big_Test__b/indexes/UUID.index-meta.xml
```

The file causes the error is the index of the **Big Object** `Big_Test__b`.

I checked the Salesforce [Metadata Coverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/55) page and `Index/Custom Index` is covered in the 2GP Managed packaging.

But the [Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_custom_objects) page in the **Salesforce DX Developer Guide** shows no information about `Big Object` or `Index`.